# Flutter Bottom Navigation Space Between Items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to make the bottom navbar as in the picture, but I'm having difficulty adjusting the spacing between the items. I used an image instead of an icon. And I gave the images width and height values. But when I wanted to reduce their whitespace, I couldn't achieve it. Can you help me with this?

image:
[image]

My Code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: !navBarHide
              ? SafeArea(
                  child: BottomNavigationBar(
                      onTap: (index) {
                        debugPrint(controller.tabIndex.toString());
                        controller.tabChange(index);
                        controller.update();
                        if (index == 0) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('dashboard');
                        } else if (index == 1) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('blank');
                        } else if (index == 2) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('home');
                        } else if (index == 3) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('blank');
                        } else if (index == 4) {
                          Get.offAndToNamed('menu');
                        }
                      },
                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                      unselectedFontSize: 0,
                      unselectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                        size: Get.width > 390 ? 24.sp : 24.sp,
                      ),
                      selectedFontSize: 0,
                      selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
                        size: Get.width > 390 ? 24.sm : 24.sm,
                      ),
                      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
                      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                      landscapeLayout:
                          BottomNavigationBarLandscapeLayout.spread,
                      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
                      selectedItemColor: Colors.orange,
                      showSelectedLabels: false,
                      showUnselectedLabels: false,
                      currentIndex: controller.tabIndex,
                      // tamamdır
                      items: [
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.card_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.key_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.home_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.doc_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                        _bottomNavbarItem(
                          AppAssets.menu_icon,
                          '',
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              : null,
```

Items Method:

```
  _bottomNavbarItem(String assetName, String label) {
return BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Image.asset(
    assetName,
    width: 25.w,
    height: 22.h,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
  ),
  activeIcon: Container(
    width: 25.w,
    height: 22.h,
    child: Image.asset(assetName),
  ),
  label: label,
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 4):

By default if there are more than 3 items the type changes to floating. You can force it to use fixed type to place all elements equally spaced

```dart
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

Comment: The code you have written already exists in the code.

Comment: You can increase the height and width of the container which will increase the size of the icons..

Comment: I don't think this is the solution

Comment: You can either increase the size of the asset or increase the size of the container. Also if you are sure of the size you can also give `fit:BoxFit.fill`